# Adding files to Sharepoint online with foldernames and language in columns

Tags: sharepoint-online

We have a bunch of files that we wan't to share with our business partners outside our organisation. The files are stored on our server fileshare for now, but for sharing purposes I'd like to move or sync them to Sharepoint Online file library. My files are all neatly arranged in folders for easier serching and since they're in multiple languages they all have prefix of the language en_ or de_ or sk_ etc... Folders are arranged by products, suppliers, documents types etc..

When moving or syncing the files to share point file library I'd like to add extra columns to each uploaded file - one for language that should somehow be recognised from prefix of filename, others for each subdirectory in which the file stands. Adding this data in columns wold greatly help filtering the data when needed.

I was looking at Power automate for solutions but I didn't find the right flow that would do what I need. Any ideas?

And another question. Is there any way to automatically filter language by some property in O365 user profile so when a user visits the Sharepoint webpage only documents in his language, English or German are displayed? I know this is hard to accomplish, but I have to ask :)

Thank you for any answer that helps me solve the problem....

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of solutions.  One uses a third party tool, but this is not the place to advertise.

The second is to compare the DetectedLanguage managed property with the user's language. Depending on the search method, one way is to make the user's profile properties indexable by search using this technique
https://sharegate.com/blog/filtering-content-with-sharepoint-user-properties-search

This works for a lot of languages, but not all of them: DetectedLanguage and the user profile do not always use the same language codes, but if it happens to match it's good.

If you are using a SharePoint feature that lets you show different pages to different users based on their language (Variations for classic pages or Multilingual Page Publishing for modern Communication sites, then you can hard-code the language based on the page.